# Join 2 tables and return the resulting one in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 tables `Patients` and `Studies` that have a shared field called `Studyid`. I need to get the study name from the `Studies` table
where `PatID` is a method's parameter.
I am joining the tables but I am failing to return the resulting one, so far I am retuning a single table to which I cannot implement the `Where` condition.

`db.Patients.Join(db.Studies, ct => ct.Studyid, st => st.Studyid, (ct, st) => st).Where(p => p.Patientstudyid == PatId).ToList()` which obviously won't work since `Studies` have no patient's information.

How to return the joined table?

Comment: IMHO, use query syntax. It is more readable and useful when using joins. Compiler will generate all need stubs to access to needed joined parts.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Open to that, please if you have an answer, post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer query syntax when using joins. It is easily to refactor and to understand what query do.

```cs
var query = 
    from p in db.Patients
    join st in db.Studies on p.Studyid equals ct.Studyid
    where p.Patientstudyid == PatId
    select st.Name;

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Yea, query syntax is just better for joins.